# Output of custom merge driver for Git

Tags: git, merge, 3-way-merge

I want to use the custom merge driver for Git. To do this I wrote the program, which takes 5 arguments `%O %A %B %L %P`as described [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) in the block *"Defining a custom merge driver"* and makes 3-way merge.

> - `%O` - ancestor’s version
> - `%A` - current brunch version
> - `%B` - other branches' version
> - `%L` - conflict marker size
> - `%P` - merge driver can learn the pathname in which the merged result will be stored via placeholder `%P`

And question is which of the five arguments I should use to write the results of the merge? I tried to write as in `%A` and `%P`, but it doesn't work.

I also found this:

> The merge driver is expected to leave the result of the merge in the
>   file named with `%A` by overwriting it, and exit with zero status if it
>   managed to merge them cleanly, or non-zero if there were conflicts.

But it also doesn't work. May be i do smth wrong?